# PHP - Can you help change this function slightly?

Tags: php

I have the following function I modified based off someone elses function:

```
function showCombinations($string, $nameString, $linkParts, $i){
    $wordDivider = "/"; //the divider between the words/values

    if ($i >= count($linkParts)){
        echo "<a href='".trim($string)."'>".trim($nameString)."</a>, ";
    } else {
        foreach ($linkParts[$i] as $currentTrait){

            if ($currentTrait['name']=="urltext"){
                $currentNameStringName=""; //ignore
            } else {
                $currentNameStringName=$currentTrait['name'];
            }

            if ($nameString!=""){
                $currentNameString=$nameString." - ".$currentNameStringName;
            } else {
                $currentNameString=$nameString.$currentNameStringName;
            }
            showCombinations($string.$currentTrait['value'].$wordDivider, $currentNameString, $linkParts, $i + 1);
        }


    }
}
showCombinations('', '', $linkParts, 0);
```

All I need to change this to do is, instead of `ECHO`, I want it to build up the combination and so I can do:

```
$result = showCombinations('', '', $linkParts, 0);
echo $result;
```

I need it this way because I have to modify that `$result`, not just echo it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

```
function showCombinations($string, $nameString, $linkParts, $i){
    $wordDivider = "/"; //the divider between the words/values
    $result = '';

    if ($i >= count($linkParts)){
        $result .= "<a href='".trim($string)."'>".trim($nameString)."</a>, ";
    } else {
        foreach ($linkParts[$i] as $currentTrait){

            if ($currentTrait['name']=="urltext"){
                $currentNameStringName=""; //ignore
            } else {
                $currentNameStringName=$currentTrait['name'];
            }

            if ($nameString!=""){
                $currentNameString=$nameString." - ".$currentNameStringName;
            } else {
                $currentNameString=$nameString.$currentNameStringName;
            }
            $result .= showCombinations($string.$currentTrait['value'].$wordDivider, $currentNameString, $linkParts, $i + 1);
        }


    }

    return $result;
}

$result = showCombinations('', '', $linkParts, 0);
echo $result;
```

Comment: oops, you forgot to return $result;

Comment: doh.. anyone know how to return it as an array instead of a string?